# How to create a Domain using coordinates, grid size and depth data?

Tags: qgis

I am using qgis and I am trying to create a domain which will have unstructured grids of approximate resolution of 0.25 degrees. I have a region bounded by coordinates(wgs84) (82,7), (82,11), (92,11), (92,7).

I need to keep the bathymetry constant i.e. 1000 metres. The grid size needs to be 0.25 degrees?

How can I create this domain?

Comment: As I understand it, a "domain" is a rule that describe the allowable values of a field. It doesn't sound like that's what you're asking for.